# How to find application user name (ASP.NET/IIS)

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to track down why when the web app accesses a network drive, I see Network path not found (error 53). When I log into the server I can open up a file on that drive with no problem. But the application (asp.net) cannot. I was wondering if this was a permissions error and that lead me to try to find out what the usename of the app is and where I would find that out.

Comment: `string NTID = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;  //Get Current user's ID`

Comment: It seems I would have to use this like in web.Config or on a code-behind page. How can I log into the server and find this out?

Comment: You can put it in the page load event of the codebehind file. It will only give you the user's NTID though

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your OS version and your security settings. Your web-site should have an app pool assigned to it (which may be shared with other applications). By default in windows server 2008R2 the pseudo account ApplicationPoolIdentity is used, which is not really an account.

[IIS Accounts](http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities)

You can check under advanced settings for the app pool and see what it is using. I believe if you have impersonation set up in your web.config, the app pool will access resources using the credentials of whomever is using the application--you can use Kieran's snippet to get that information.